# Fast computation of matrix product $AXA^T$ with fixed $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we have two $n$-by-$n$ matrices $X$ and $A$, where $A$ is known and $X$ may change in different invocations, and we want to compute $AXA^T$. Is there an algorithm that beats the naive one of computing $AX$, then multiply the result by $A^T$?

Comment: We don't know how fast [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Sub-cubic_algorithms) can be made: it seems the current best (due to Le Gall) is $O(n^{2.3728639})$, but there are grounds for believing that there are $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ algorithms for every $\epsilon > 0$.
It's hard to imagine how an algorithm for $A X A^T$ could do better than that.

Comment: If the X's differ by small amounts, one can precompute the differences on a basis and then use linear combinations of the differences.  This can save on a lot of multiplication.  Gerhard "Think Like It's Differential Encoding" Paseman, 2018.06.13.

Comment: To add to Robert's comment, note that every entry of $X$ is needed just to find one entry of $AXA^T$.  So even finding one entry of the answer requires $\Omega(n^2)$ time; what chance of finding all the entries in just a little more time?

Comment: Is $X$ symmetric? Do successive instances of $X$ differ by a known low-rank matrix?

Comment: I might also mention that if there is an $O(n^\alpha)$ algorithm for $X \to A X A^T$, there are also $O(n^\alpha)$ algorithms for $X \to (A X \ \text{and}\ X A^T)$, since $$\pmatrix{0 & I\cr A & 0} \pmatrix{0 & X\cr X & 0\cr} \pmatrix{0 & A^T \cr I & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{0 &  X A^T\cr A X & 0}$$